# How to load npm packages with ClosureCompiler.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-closure-compiler

I want to try [Google Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/), so I'm using it with the npm distribution [closurecompiler.js](https://github.com/dcodeIO/ClosureCompiler.js). I'm using the closure compiler to traspile my es6 code to es5. It's not an option to change to babel transpiler.

So I started with some basic examples, and those worked fine, but I'm stuck importing some npm packages. This are my dependencies, from my `package.json` file

```
"dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.5.2",
    "express": "~4.7.2",
    "method-override": "~2.1.2",
    "mongoose": "~3.6.2",
    "morgan": "~1.2.2",
    "vue": "^1.0.16",
    "vue-resource": "^0.7.0"
  }
```

Running the `require` command it is all working but if I run

```
import express from 'express'
```

I got the error

```
server.js:4: ERROR - Failed to load module "express"
  import express  from 'express'
  ^
```

the command used to make the transpile was

```
ccjs config/*.js server.js --externs=node > dist/server.js && node dist/server.js
```

I've tried it with and without the `--externs=node` option, but nothing changes. Note that sentences like

```
import database from './config/database'
```

works fine, the problem is only for the node_modules packages. So, how can I make those import work with closure compiler??

Answer (score 2):

The `--js_module_root` flag tells the compiler where modules are found. By default it looks only in the current directory, so you probably need to pass the `node_modules` directory as well, to make this work.

I haven't used the compiler with node myself but I think that should be all you need. If that works, please update the documentation at https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/JS-Modules or comment here to remind us to do that.

Comment: I'll check this as soon as I can, but it seems that I'll need to check against the `.jar` compiler, because the npm package that I'm using doesn't seems to have the `--js_module_root` option

Comment: @YerkoPalma You may want to switch to the official npm distribution/package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-closure-compiler Many of the 3rd party packages have compiler versions that are very old/outdated.

Comment: @YerkoPalma did you manage to solve this issue importing node_modules in your es6 js to compile with closure compiler? I am having the same problem and can't figure out what value to give to `--js_module_root`, I tried many values and none of them works. It works fine, as you said, with my modules, the only problem is with node_modules..

Answer (score 1):

The trick was to pass the referenced files and package.json to the closure compiler using **--js** argument. Something like this:

```
java\
 -jar node_modules/google-closure-compiler/compiler.jar\
 --compilation_level=ADVANCED\
 --process_common_js_modules\
 --dependency_mode=STRICT\
 --js_output_file='./dist/compiled.js'\
 --module_resolution=NODE\
 --entry_point=./src/module\
 --js='./src/**.js'\
 --js='./node_modules/isarray/**.js'\
 --js='./node_modules/isarray/**package.json'
```

Check [here](https://github.com/germanz/google-closure-compiler-simple-test/blob/master/compile.sh).

However with **express** it is tricky, as it brings bunch of dependencies and compiler reports tons of errors on them.